Import a single symbol from txfonts
I'm writing a document, and I need to import only the union symbol (\cup) from the txfonts font. However, every attempt I make ends up importing all the symbols from that font, not just the symbol I need.
For reference, I've already read the majority of topics about this issue, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I opened the txfonts.sty, looked for the relevant code and tried to adapt as in those previous topics. I even tried with the code in this file omstxsy.fd, but was I was unsuccessful.
This is the code I ended up writing:
\documentclass{article}

% (From: https://mirrors.up.pt/pub/CTAN/fonts/txfonts/input/txfonts.sty)
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\newcup}{\mathbin}{symbols}{91}

\begin{document}
    \[  A \cup B \newcup C \cup D   \]
    \centering Normal text ...
    \[  \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i   \]
\end{document}


In this image, all the union symbols are from the txfonts font; the one between B and C should be the only in txfonts. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

You should declare a new symbol font: symbols is preempted.
\documentclass{article}

% (From: https://mirrors.up.pt/pub/CTAN/fonts/txfonts/input/txfonts.sty)
\DeclareSymbolFont{additionalsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{additionalsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\newcup}{\mathbin}{additionalsymbols}{91}

\begin{document}

\[  A \cup B \newcup C \cup D   \]
\centering Normal text ...
\[  \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i   \]

\end{document}


I'm not sure anybody can distinguish between \cup and \newcup.

Wow, it was that simple! Thank you, it worked.
I agree, it is hard to notice a difference between the 2 union symbols, I just wanted to use this union symbol with a new math font that I think matches better. It's purely for aesthetics lol
